# CV: Reduce image encapsulating column-width in tabular environment

Tags: tables, graphics

I am using the following tabular code to create the top listing of my CV.  However, I can't seem to get the width of the column containing the images to be narrower, as it looks out of place as it is.

Is there any way to "scrunch" down column size so there's not much whitespace around the images?

Or, could I force the text on the right side to jump to the left?  Isn't there a negative space command?

```
\begin{tabular}{p{4.5in}cp{3in}}\\
\huge{Dr. First Lastname}              & \includegraphics[width=0.1in,keepaspectratio]{email}     & My City, State Zip, USA\\
\normalsize\textit{Curriculum Vitae}   & \includegraphics[width=0.15in,keepaspectratio]{emailat}  & myemail@server.com\\
                                       & \includegraphics[width=0.1in,keepaspectratio]{globe}     & www.mysite.com\\
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: `p{4.5in}c@{}>{\hskip1mm}p{3in}` should work

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, just use a negative \hspace value before the text on the right side:

```
\begin{tabular}{p{4.5in}cp{3in}}\\
\huge{Dr. First Lastname}              & \includegraphics[width=0.1in,keepaspectratio]{email}     & \hspace{-15pt} My City, State Zip, USA\\
\normalsize\textit{Curriculum Vitae}   & \includegraphics[width=0.15in,keepaspectratio]{emailat}  & \hspace{-15pt} myemail@server.com\\
                                       & \includegraphics[width=0.1in,keepaspectratio]{globe}     & \hspace{-15pt} www.mysite.com\\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: there is no need to use negative space to remove space you are adding, it is better not to add the space. eg use `c@{}p{3in}` or better `c@{}l` also note `\huge` does not take an argument, so `\huge Dr. First Lastname` not `\huge{Dr. First Lastname}`, you do not need `keepaspectratio` in `\includegraphics` as you have only specified `width`, not `width` and `height`.

Comment: @David Carlisle - Thank you so much - all your suggestions worked!